# mongodb query with limit on sum of documents fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have documents like below in my collection in mongodb named orders:

```
{quantity: 0.1, price: 5, timestamp: 1686402815}
{quantity: 0.13, price: 4.9, timestamp: 1686401801}
{quantity: 0.27, price: 4.1, timestamp: 1686402850}
{quantity: 0.5, price: 5, timestamp: 1686403050}
....
```

i have about 200K documents, and i want to retrieve documents sorted by price and timestamp, after sort:

```
{quantity: 0.1, price: 5, timestamp: 1686402815}
{quantity: 0.5, price: 5, timestamp: 1686403050}
{quantity: 0.13, price: 4.9, timestamp: 1686401801}
{quantity: 0.27, price: 4.1, timestamp: 1686402850}
....
```

i want to get those documents which sum of their quantities (quantity field) as long as sum become greater than 0.62, i mean i want only these three records:

```
{quantity: 0.1, price: 5, timestamp: 1686402815}
{quantity: 0.5, price: 5, timestamp: 1686403050}
{quantity: 0.13, price: 4.9, timestamp: 1686401801}
```

how can i make a query to do this operation in nodejs with mongodb module?
thanks.

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76443825/20042973)?

Comment: [`"$setWindowFields"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) could be useful here.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "price": -1,
        "timestamp": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "cumSumQ": {
          "$sum": "$quantity",
          "window": {
            "documents": ["unbounded", "current"]
          }
        },
        "cumSumQm1": {
          "$sum": "$quantity",
          "window": {
            "documents": ["unbounded", -1]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {"cumSumQ": {"$lte": 0.62}},
        {
          "$and": [
            {"cumSumQ": {"$gt": 0.62}},
            {"cumSumQm1": {"$lte": 0.62}}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": ["_id", "cumSumQ", "cumSumQm1"]
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wI7zLgWltF7).